# Run script in response to error occurrence

Tags: shell, hadoop, apache-pig, oozie, hue

Is there any way to run script (Pig, shell) in response to error occurrence? I mean: I create workflow in Oozie (Workflow Manager) and one of task fail and call error, and if this error occur i want to run specific script or another task. I want provide some kind of error handling:

- When error1 occur - do something
- When error2 occur - do somthing else

I will be gratefull for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Error handling you can use [Decision nodes](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.1.4_Decision_Control_Node). For example:

```
<action name="Action1">
    <map-reduce>
        <job-tracker>foo:9001</job-tracker>
        <name-node>bar:9000</name-node>
        <job-xml>job1.xml</job-xml>
    </map-reduce>
    <ok to="NextAction"/>
    <error to="ErrorhandlingDecision"/>
</action>
<decision name="ErrorhandlingDecision">
    <switch>
        <case to="CorrectError1Node">
          ${wf:errorCode("SourceActionNodeName") eq "JA018"}
        </case>
        <case to="CorrectError2Node">
          ${errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode()) eq "Error Msg Received"}
        </case>
        <default to="NextAction"/>
    </switch>
</decision>
```

All you need to catch the Error code or error message.

Note: Expression Lang (EL) support following operation

one of ["}", ".", ">", "gt", "<", "lt", "==", "eq", "<=", "le", ">=", "ge", "!=", "ne", "[", "+", "-", "*", "/", "div", "%", "mod", "and", "&&", "or", "||", "?"]

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If error1 & error2 occurs in same workflow action, then change your workflow to java action & write your error handling logic there [Its not possible in workflow]. If those errors are part of different actions, try the following.

Try this:

```
<action name="firstjob">
    <map-reduce>
        <job-tracker>foo:9001</job-tracker>
        <name-node>bar:9000</name-node>
        <job-xml>job1.xml</job-xml>
    </map-reduce>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="errorscript1"/>
</action>
<action name="secondjob">
    <map-reduce>
        <job-tracker>foo:9001</job-tracker>
        <name-node>bar:9000</name-node>
        <job-xml>job2.xml</job-xml>
    </map-reduce>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="errorscript2"/>
</action>
<action name="errorscript1">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
    </shell>
    <ok to="decide"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
<action name="errorscript2">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
    </shell>
    <ok to="decide"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

If using [Hue](http://gethue.com) Oozie workflow editor, currently there is no way to have the 'error' link send to another node than the 'kill' node: https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-1457

Comment: Thanks. It's Cloudera issue, is it the same issue with Hortonworks Hue Job Editor?